# How to disable windows keys programmatically?

Tags: java, windows

I want to write a programm which will start Chrome or Firefox browser in full screen with a given URL and will also disable windows keys so that the user can not come out of full screen mode.

User should not be able to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> or press windows keys or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> etc.

What is the best way to do this? In which programming languages it will be easy to do this?

Comment: Have a look into Windows Kiosk Apps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Comment: thanks for the reply. we want to run programme in windows 7/8/10.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Winform. WinForms is a graphical (GUI) class library included as a part of Microsoft .NET Framework or Mono Framework, providing a platform to write rich client applications for desktop, laptop, and tablet PCs